# Comparing parsed integer values returning wrong java

Tags: java

I have a genreic object Class. When I add integers to the object and compare them it is returning the wrong answer.

```
    bsTree<Integer> tree = new bsTree<Integer>();
    tree.add(6);
```

Then in the comparison

```
add(T value) {
Node nodeWithData = root;

System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(value.toString) <= Integer.parse(nodeWithData.getContent().toString())
}
```

The node content is equal to 5 but it prints true. Why?

Current code that compiles

```
public class bsTree<T> {
private bNode root;
private bNode currentNode = root;


public bsTree()
{
    root = null;
}
public bsTree(T[] anArray)
{
    if(anArray==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<anArray.length; i++)
    {
        add(anArray[i]);
    }
}

public void add(T value)
{

    if(root == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Setting first node to " + value);

        root = new bNode(value);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //System.out.println("Value is = " + value);            
        currentNode = root;

        while(currentNode != null)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(currentNode.getContent().toString()) <= Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))
            {
                System.out.println(value + " <= " + currentNode.getContent());

                if(currentNode.getlChild() == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Setting left Child");
                    currentNode.setlChild(new bNode(value));
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Going left");
                    currentNode = currentNode.getlChild();
                }

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    bsTree<Integer> tree = new bsTree<Integer>();

    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(7);
    tree.add(8);
    tree.add(9);

}


}
```

Comment: because you are printing out the result of a conditional operator

Comment: But the conditional is technically 6 <= 5 which is incorrect.

Comment: You seem to be missing the () from the call to toString(), not sure if that's the cause, or just something to check.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with your debugger, or logged values to validate your assumptions?

Comment: @MattCoubrough I have stepped through my code and my suspicion is that when the value is parsed there is something going on that I am not aware of. David Wallace it compiles and everything except this works as expected. Alan sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: OK, how about you paste in the code that you're actually running, rather than just incrementally updating your post in the hope of converging on something that will compile?

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok but I am creating a binary tree so the code may be rather lengthy.

Comment: It does NOT compile in its current form.  And it didn't compile in the form it was in when I made my previous comment.  What you've done is a bit like asking us to find a needle in a haystack, but only giving as a photo of the haystack, instead of the haystack itself.

Comment: @DavidWallace The whole code that I am currently running

Comment: Can you see the difference between the code you posted first and the code you've posted now? hint: `parseInt` != `parse`

Comment: @MattCoubrough I do indeed, nevertheless the problem is still the same. Rather than the incorrect formatting, forgive my rushing.

Comment: Will you post the `bNode` class?  The problem might be there.

Comment: Sorry - It's hard to forgive bad questions that waste a lot of people's time commenting and trying to run bad code.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Understandable. Can you explain why the code does not function correctly?

Comment: You already have an answer, but that answer could not have been given to you until you posted the ACTUAL code you are running. Hopefully you will have learned a valuable lesson about how to ask a good question in future.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Thank you for your valuable commenting and critiquing of my question. My meager 130 (currently) reputation does not compare to your well over 1,000. Such a simple problem should not have even been posted on here. To add to that, my years of programming should definitely have caught this novice mistake. But I do value my rep, so in the future I will make sure I focus on asking great questions so I do not get docked. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the opposite of your test. You test `currentNode` <= `value`, but print the reverse.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(currentNode.getContent().toString()) <= 
    Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))
{
  System.out.println(value + " <= " + currentNode.getContent());
```

should be

```
if(Integer.parseInt(currentNode.getContent().toString()) <= 
    Integer.parseInt(value.toString()))
{
  System.out.println(currentNode.getContent() + " <= " + value);
```

Comment: Well found, Elliott. And I was hoping the problem would be something interesting. :-(

Comment: I feel ashamed for even posting this now.